# Группировка меток по регионам

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как реализовать такой функционал через Яндекс Карты:
http://gazpromnoncoreassets.ru

Есть несколько сотен объектов недвижимости, каждый из которых привязан к региону России. Изначально нужно вывести метки регионов, причем по каждому региону нужно вывести количество объектов недвижимости.

При увеличении масштаба карты нужно выводить метки объектов недвижимости по конкретному региону. При уменьшении масштаба карты нужно снова отображать метки регионов с количеством объектов по каждому региону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте, который вы привели в пример, используется обычная кластеризация, без привязки в региону. Фактически метки сливаются в одну, если попадают в общую "ячейку", то есть могут склеиться метки из соседних регионов, если они ближе друг к другу, чем к другим меткам "своего" региона. Это видно на вашей карте при изменении масштаба.

Такое поведение сделать легко. [Вот пример.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create?from=SO)

Если необходимо настроить логику с четким разделением по регионам, то придется отслеживать изменения масштаба самостоятельно. Например на уровнях зума 0-6 показывать кастомные метки с названием региона и количеством объявлений в нём, а при масштабе > 6 - отображать метки объявлений.